# Como oculto la consola de Windows para un programa con interfaz SFML en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy usando un IDE llamado Clion para programar en C++ y la biblioteca SFML para crear la ventana de mi aplicación pero lo que no me gusta es que la consola de windows se abre siempre con la ventana de mi programa y me molesta mucho.

Este es el código de mi_proyecto.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(15));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

y el archivo CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(mi_proyecto)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system window graphics)
add_executable(mi_proyecto main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mi_proyecto sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics -static)
```

Este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obtén el puntero a la ventana de consola ([documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow)):

   ```
   auto consola = GetConsoleWindow();
   ```
2. Ocúltala ([documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow)):

   ```
   ShowWindow(consola, SW_HIDE);
   ```

O tal vez, sea mejor cambiar las propiedades del proyecto para que no sea considerado un proyecto de consola ([documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-160)):

[image]